# uploading and form data into database simultaneously

Tags: php

i am creating  html form which take input from form and store in a database and take an image from user and store in a same table

i  already create image field of BLOB date type in my table

but problem is both of the task is not working simultaneosly

//my html code

```
Scholarship name (association name) :<input type ="text" name ="name"/>
Scholarship type (merit/need) :<input type ="text" name ="type"/>
Amount offer by Scholar ship :<input type ="text" name ="rupees"/>
Last date of submission :<input type ="text" name ="last_date"/>
Number of student that can apply :<input type ="text" name ="total_students"/>
 Tagline about scholarship :<input type ="text" name ="tagline"/>
Scholarship criteria(zakaat/profit) :<input type ="text" name ="criteria"/> 
Contact number:<input type ="text" name ="cellno1"/>
Email Address:<input type ="text" name ="email"/>
Scholarship description : <TEXTAREA Name="description" ROWS=2 COLS=20></TEXTAREA>
<input type="file" name="file" /> </br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload and submit">
```

//my php code

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','******','scholarships_system') or die ('you\'re dead');
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) && (isset($_FILES['file'])== true)) {

$name= $_POST['name'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$rupees = $_POST['rupees'];
$last_date = $_POST['last_date'];
$total_students = $_POST['total_students'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$data = addslashes(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']));
$myquery="INSERT INTO scholarship_details  VALUES('','$name','$type','$rupees','$last_date','$total_students','$description'$data)";
if($update=$mysql->query($myquery)or die($mysql->error)){
echo 'congraxx';
}
}
?>
```

/// please help me tommorow is my code submission and no error  is comming

Comment: And where's the code which saves image to db?

Comment: Why do you use `addslashes()` instead of `real_escape_string`? And why don't you escape any of the $_POST inputs? That's a **big** security hole!

Comment: for one you're not doing anything with $data, the contents of your image. Shouldn't that be added to the insert query? Or better yet, not stored in the database at all but instead in a file directory?

Comment: ya i am sorry i already have done that i post the query

Comment: my code is still not working please do help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo your `$myquery` variable and you'll see you're missing a comma between `'$description'` and `$data`. Also, you are missing single quotes `'` wrapping `$data`.

```
$myquery="INSERT INTO scholarship_details  VALUES('','$name','$type','$rupees','$last_date','$total_students','$description'$data)";
```

Should be

```
$myquery="INSERT INTO scholarship_details  VALUES('','$name','$type','$rupees','$last_date','$total_students','$description','$data')";
```

Nevertheless, I don't see a point to store the image in the DB, unless you have your own reasons to do that. If that is not the case, save it in your file directory and store `/path/to/the/image_file.ext` in your database.

Comment: Hey @qasu still no progress?